# Combining list in a Cartesian product format with addition operation?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two list to begin with.

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3};
list2 = {10, 20, 30, 40};
```

I want to obtain the following output (order unimportant):

```
{11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43}
```

I can obtain it via "Table, For, Do" etc.  command but I am looking for a concise code to achieve such an output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Outer[Plus, list2, list1] // Flatten
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A variation of Coolwater's answer:

```
Tuples @ Unevaluated[{10, 20, 30, 40} + {1,2,3}]
```

> {11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43}

Answer (score 3):

```
Total[Tuples[{list2, list1}], {2}]
(* {11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list1+#&/@list2//Flatten

(*{11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33,41,42,43}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Thread`:** (and letting it morph into `MapThread`)

```
Sequence @@@ (Thread[# + list1] & /@ list2)

Sequence @@@ (Map[Thread[# + list1] &, list2])

Sequence @@@ 
 MapThread[Plus, {list2, ConstantArray[list1, Length@list2]}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43}

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3};
l2 = {10, 20, 30, 40};
```

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
f = Table[#, Length@l1 + 1] + Range@Length@# &;

Flatten@Thread@Most@SubsetMap[f, #, All] &@l2

(*{11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43}*)
```

Another very nice solution (Thanks to @Syed!) is the following:

```
Flatten@Thread[# + l2 & /@ l1]

(*{11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43}*)
```

Comment: simpler: `Flatten@Thread[# + l2 & /@ l1]`. I am trying to say that `SubsetMap[...,All]` implies that `Map` can be used instead.

Comment: Clever solution, Syed! :-)